# django - NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.posts_id

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to have a comment form be submitted by the user to the respective blog. I'm getting the error "NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.posts_id" when I do that.

views.py

```
def add_comment(request, slug):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', slug=post.slug)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
template = "blog/post/add_comment.html"
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, template, context)
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('user', 'email', 'title', 'body',)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOISES = (

    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),

    )
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
content = models.TextField()
seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
seo_description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', default=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS_CHOISES, default='draft')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.slug])


def __str__(self):
    return self.title



class Comment(models.Model):
    posts = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    user = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approved(self):
        self.approved = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

What is wrong with my code?

From what I understand, somewhere/somehow the comment is not being sent to the right blog post, because if I give my form a post field and manually select it, it works. But ideally, I'd want it to be automatically sent to the corresponding blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ForeignKey` of `Post` model in `Comment` model is named as `posts` not as `post`, hence you need to do:

```
if form.is_valid():
    comment = form.save(commit=False)
    comment.posts = post
    comment.save()
```

It makes more sense to just rename your ForeignKey and name it as `post`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
```

Comment: You're right, I was renaming things to test things out and see what exactly they do (I'm following a tutorial and I'm pausing to try to understand what's going on) and I forgot to rename that back.. I wouldn't have noticed it without your help! Thanks so much!! It works now :D